# Change string to list when the string is already in list form

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings:

`list1=['[206,397]', '[207,397]', '[208,397]', '[209,397]', '[210,397]', '[211,399]']`

and I want this output:

```
list1=[[206,397], [207,397], [208,397], [209,397], [210,397], [211,399]]
```

I tried several ways to convert the strings to lists, but I did not manage to get my desired output.

Here is what I did:

```
for i in list1:
   i=list(i)
```

No change was made to list1

I tried again with another approach:

```
list1=['[206,397]', '[207,397]', '[208,397]', '[209,397]', '[210,397]', '[211,399]']
list2=[]
for i in list1:
  list2.append(list(i))
```

This time the output is something like this:

```
[['[', '2', '0', '6', ',', '3', '9', '7', ']'], ['[', '2', '0', '7', ',', '3', '9', '7', ']'], ['[', '2', '0', '8', ',', '3', '9', '7', ']'], ['[', '2', '0', '9', ',', '3', '9', '7', ']'], ['[', '2', '1', '0', ',', '3', '9', '7', ']'], ['[', '2', '1', '1', ',', '3', '9', '9', ']']]
```

Can you help me with this? Thanks in advance for any help you can give

Comment: Will your contained strings always be valid JSON, i.e. could you use a JSON parser? That's probably safer than just evaluating the string. (And you should probably tag the question python if that's what this is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple and easy to understand Python code is also this step-by-step code:

```
list1=['[206,397]', '[207,397]', '[208,397]', '[209,397]', '[210,397]', '[211,399]']

resultList = []

for entry in list1:

    entry = entry.replace("[", "") # Trims [
    entry = entry.replace("]", "") # Trims ]

    number1 = int(entry.split(",")[0]) # Splits by comma and converts to integer
    number2 = int(entry.split(",")[1]) # Splits by comma and converts to integer

    resultList.append([number1, number2]) # Append to resultList

print(resultList)
```

This produces final result:

`[[206, 397], [207, 397], [208, 397], [209, 397], [210, 397], [211, 399]]`

Answer (score 1):

JSON parsing may be appropriate as mentioned in the comments, but this would also work with the data sample you've provided. I wasn't sure if you wanted your results to be a list of lists of strings, or a list of lists of ints. Ignore the second line if the former is what you want.

```
list2 = [x[1:-1].split(',') for x in list1]
list3 = [[int(x) for x in y] for y in list2]

print(list3)
# [[206, 397], [207, 397], [208, 397], [209, 397], [210, 397], [211, 399]]
```

Edit to add: can be condensed to a one-liner if preferred:

```
list4 = [[int(y) for y in x[1:-1].split(',')] for x in list1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

So the code for generating the list would be : -

```
import ast
list1=['[206,397]', '[207,397]', '[208,397]', '[209,397]', '[210,397]', '[211,399]']
list2=[]
for i in list1:
  list2.append(ast.literal_eval(i))
```

**Note** : Don't forget to `import ast`

Screenshot of output:-
[image: Output]